# Tailwind CSS: change parent label style when a child checkbox is checked

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to add the add a border to my checkbox container when the checkbox is checked.

Currently, I have this:

```html
<label
  htmlFor="choose-me"
  className=
    'flex w-fit items-center justify-evely p-3 border-2 border-grey-4 text-grey-8 
     peer-checked:bg-light-indigo peer-checked:text-medium-indigo peer-checked:border-medium-indigo'>
  <input type="checkbox" id="choose-me" className="peer mr-3 " />
  Check me
</label>
```

I want something like the below:

[image: checkbox - checked and unchecked]

However, I am unable to change the label styles when I put my input inside the label.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: Handle it using useState

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A CSS-only solution would be to use the `:has` pseudo-selector (note: not supported yet in Firefox). This would apply the classes only if the label wraps a checkbox which has been checked.

**index.css**

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .checkbox-label:has(input:checked) {
    @apply border-blue-800 bg-blue-400 text-blue-800;
  }
}
```

**Your JSX:** (with the unused classes stripped out)

```html
<label className="checkbox-label justify-evely border-grey-4 text-grey-8 flex w-fit items-center gap-x-2 border-2 p-3">
  <input type="checkbox" id="choose-me" />
  Check me
</label>
```

You can test it here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/zidP4zm2Pq

The list of browsers supporting `:has`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#browser_compatibility

Comment: `has()` is now fully supported in Firefox, as well as all other major browsers.

Answer (score 1):

First off, it's important to remember that the `peer` functionality in tailwind doesn't target parents (which is what you currently have). You can only target elements that are next to one another.

Additionally, because of how the CSS `:peer` combinator works you can only target *previous* components, meaning the checkbox MUST come before the peer who's state you want to affect when the checkbox is checked.

```html
<label
  htmlFor="choose-me"
  class=
    'flex w-fit items-center justify-evely p-3 text-grey-8 relative'
>
  <input type="checkbox" id="choose-me" class="peer mr-3 relative z-10" />
  <div class="absolute inset-0 border-2 border-grey-4 peer-checked:bg-indigo-200 peer-checked:text-indigo-800 peer-checked:border-indigo-800 peer-checked:block z-0"></div>
  <span class="relative z-10">Check me</span>
</label>
```

Here's an example that works using pure tailwind/css, assuming you don't want to handle the state in your react component, as per @Vikesir's comment (though that was my first thought as well and it's a good idea).

You'll notice I'm fudging in an empty div and using that to simulate the background and border changing. I also wrapped the label text in a span to make sure I could change it's z-index so that both the checkbox and the text were visible above the div that handles the state change.

**EDIT:**

Here is a version using a pseudo-element built off of the span holding the label text if you don't want the empty `div` in your code:

```
<label
  htmlFor="choose-me"
  class=
    'flex w-fit items-center justify-evely text-grey-8 relative'
>
  <input type="checkbox" id="choose-me" class="peer mr-3 absolute left-2.5 z-20" />
  <span class="relative z-10 inset-0 py-3 pr-3 pl-8 before:-z-10 before:content-[''] before:absolute before:inset-0 before:h-full before:w-full before:border-2 before:border-grey-4 peer-checked:before:bg-indigo-200 peer-checked:before:text-indigo-800 peer-checked:before:border-indigo-800 peer-checked:before:block">Check me</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

use useState for handle active state:

```
const [isactive,setActive] = useState(false)
```

in JSX:

```
<label
  onClick={()=>setActive(isactive?false:true)}
  className= {`${isactive?'active-style':'normal-style'} extra-style-classes`}
>
  <input type="checkbox" id="choose-me" className= {`${isactive?'active-style':'normal-style'} extra-style-classes`} />
  Check me
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    STEP 1: Update checkbox-label in the label tag
    <label className="checkbox-label">
    
    STEP 2: add below code in index.css file
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
    
    @layer components {
      .checkbox-label:has(input:checked) {
        @apply text-gray-700;
      }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).